# Algorithm in Module behaves different

Tags: algorithm

In my Notebook i wrote this algorithm:

```
In[63]:= mData = Import["Desktop/a.txt", {"Data", {All}, {All}}];
In[64]:= mErrors = mData[[All, 3]];
In[65]:= mWeightedErrors = 1/mErrors^2;
In[66]:= Mean[WeightedData[mData[[All, {2}]], mWeightedErrors]]
Out[66]:= 16.2181
In[67]:= ErrorOfWeightedMean = Sqrt[1/Total[mWeightedErrors]]
Out[67]:= 0.0497844
```

and everythings works fine. Now I want to put this all in one definition, but it doesn´t work:

```
In[95]:=mWeightedErrorMean[filename_] := 
Module[{filename0 = filename, mData, mErrors, mWeightedErrors, 
mWeightedErrorMeanValue, mErrorOfWeightedMean},

mData = Import[filename0, {"Data", {All}, {All}}]; 
mErrors = mData[[All, 3]];
mWeightedErrors = 1/mErrors^2;
mWeightedErrorMeanValue = 
Mean[WeightedData[mData[[All, {2}]], mWeightedErrors]];
mErrorOfWeightedMean = Sqrt[1/Total[mWeightedErrors]];

Print["Der gewichtete Mittelwert ist: " mWeightedErrorMeanValue " \
und der Fehler dazu ist: " mErrorOfWeightedMean] 
]
```

If I try to use the function there is just an odd output:

```
In[96]:= mWeightedErrorMean["Desktop/a.txt"]
         0.807407 Der gewichtete Mittelwert ist:   und der Fehler dazu ist:
```

What did I wrong? I am new to Mathematica, so probably something very fundamental.

Comment: You are missing commas in your last line: use `Print["Der gewichtete Mittelwert ist: ", mWeightedErrorMeanValue ," \
und der Fehler dazu ist: ", mErrorOfWeightedMean] ` instead.

Comment: ... compare `Print["xyz :" 3 "  abc :" 5]` versus `Print["xyz :" , 3 , "  abc :", 5]`. Also `Print` is redundant here; you can  use `Row[{"xyz :" , 3 , "  abc :", 5}]` or
`StringForm["xyz :``  abc :``", 3, 5]`  or (with `a=3` and `b=5` in the roles of your `mWeightedErrorMeanValue` and `mErrorOfWeightedMean` )  `StringJoin["xyz :" , ToString@a , "  abc :", ToString@b]` without the need for `Print`.

Comment: Luca, i posted the comments as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing commas in your last line. Use

```
Print["Der gewichtete Mittelwert ist: ", mWeightedErrorMeanValue ,
  " \ und der Fehler dazu ist: ", mErrorOfWeightedMean]
```

With `a=3` and `b=5` in the roles of your `mWeightedErrorMeanValue` and `mErrorOfWeightedMean`, respectively, compare

```
Print["xyz :" a " abc :" b]
```

> 15   abc : xyz :

versus

```
Print["xyz :" , a , " abc :", b]
```

> xyz :3  abc :5

Also check

```
"xyz :" a "  abc :" b // Head
```

> Times

By the way, `Print` is redundant here; you can use

```
Row[{"xyz :" , a , " abc :", b}]
```

> xyz :3  abc :5

or

```
StringForm["xyz :`` abc :``", 3, 5]
```

> xyz :3  abc :5

or

```
StringJoin["xyz :" , ToString@a , " abc :", ToString@b]
```

> xyz :3  abc :5

without the need for `Print`.